# MatFormFieldControl implement is not working

Tags: angular5

On dev brach,I have implemented MatFormFieldControl then use it inside mat-form-field . I also pack it (tgz) to use as lib. 
On main site there is error said "mat-form-field must contain a MatFormFieldControl." even though it work perfectly on dev.

PS. I'm not english native. Pardon me if I make you confused

how i use it

```
<mat-form-field>
  <ax-mat-time-picker></ax-mat-time-picker>
</mat-form-field>
```

this is  template

```
  <div [formGroup]="parts">
    <input matInput type="number" >
    <input matInput type="number" >
    <input matInput type="number">
    <input matInput  type="text">
  </div>
```

this is typescript

```
    @Component({
  selector: 'ax-mat-time-picker',
  exportAs: 'axMatTimePicker',
  templateUrl: './time-picker.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./time-picker.component.scss'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
  preserveWhitespaces: false,
  providers: [
    { provide: MatFormFieldControl, useExisting: AxMatTimePicker },
    DecimalPipe
  ],
  host: {
    'class': 'ax-mat-time-picker',
    '[class.floating]': 'shouldLabelFloat',
    '[id]': 'id',
    '[attr.aria-describedby]': 'describedBy'
  }
})
export class AxMatTimePicker implements MatFormFieldControl<Time>, OnDestroy {...}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe your issue is that each of the fields in your form is not bound to data in the TS.

You should change your template to actually use a form and create a formGroup with values that your form values can bind to. You do this with the "formControlName" directive in the HTML and a "FormGroup" object containing "FormControl" elements in the TS.

Don't forget to import "ReactiveFormsModule" in your module.ts and  "AbstractControl, FormBuilder, FormControl, FormGroup, FormArray" in your component.ts.

Example:
HTML

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
    <mat-form-field>
        <input matInput formControlName="name" placeholder="Name">
    </mat-form-field>
    <mat-form-field>
        <input matInput formControlName="email" placeholder="Email">
    </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

TS

```
form = new FormGroup({
    name: new FormControl(),
    email: new FormControl()
});
```